# Save PDF from Webview on Android

Tags: android, pdf, printing, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I want to save my webview to a PDF file. I know that I can print the WebView with WebView.createPrintDocumentAdapter() and PrintManager.print().
But I need a way to save the PDF, that is generated internally by the PrintDocumentAdapter, directly without any user interactions, because I need the file for further processing inside my app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I realise this question is quite old now. But I have just realised how this can be sensibly done.

Essentially as per the question you can use the `createPrintDocumentAdapter` method mentioned above and pass the result to your own "fake" PrintManager implementation which simply overrides the onWrite method to save the output to your own file. The snippet below shows how to take any `PrintDocumentAdapter` and send the output from it to a file.

```
public void print(PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter, final File path, final String fileName) {
    printAdapter.onLayout(null, printAttributes, null, new PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLayoutFinished(PrintDocumentInfo info, boolean changed) {
            printAdapter.onWrite(null, getOutputFile(path, fileName), new CancellationSignal(), new PrintDocumentAdapter.WriteResultCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onWriteFinished(PageRange[] pages) {
                    super.onWriteFinished(pages);
                }
            });
        }
    }, null);
}
```

As you can see there's quite a few nulls passed into the adapters methods but I have checked the Chromium source code and these variables are never used so the nulls are ok.

I created a blog post about how to do it here:
http://www.annalytics.co.uk/android/pdf/2017/04/06/Save-PDF-From-An-Android-WebView/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is exactly what was my solution. Unfortunately, I forgot to update this page. Look at this question to use a other package than android.print, maybe you want to update your blog post :)

Comment: @Andreas thanks for the answer, I saw your blog post about this, but how to create a class in android.print package, It's a system package ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post the link of the question I mentioned.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353382/instance-of-abstract-class-with-hidden-constructor With this solution there is no need to create a class in the android.print package

Comment: @BrettCherrington Hey may I know what you meant about this: placed in the `android.print` package

Comment: @hyperfkcb Sorry for the delayed reply. You have to put the above in a class in the `android.print` package because it makes use of package level protected methods/classes.

Comment: @Andreas above solution provide in link is working but i can't create multiple pages can you help me to solve it? here's my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870164/convert-html-into-pdf-using-webview-can-not-created-multiple-pages

Comment: @BrettCherrington Can it be done in a way that the pdf is both saved in a file and also shown in the WebView?

Answer (score -1):

Create a custom `WebViewClient` ([reference](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html)) and set it on your `WebView`.

In this `WebViewClient` you should override `shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url)`. From here on you can download the PDF manually when it is clicked.

Comment: They asked to save the contents of the WebView as a pdf. Not download an existing pdf file.

Comment: @FabianStreitel Hence I suggested to override the WebView behaviour: this allows you to intercept the URL loading and download it instead. In practice you'd probably show a native Android popup to ask the user if he wants to view the PDF or download it.