# Instance of abstract class with hidden constructor

Tags: java, android, reflection, abstract-class

I need to create an instance of an abstract class with hidden constructor, the class looks like the following:

```
public abstract class TestClass {
    /**
    * @hide
    */
    public TestClass() {
    }
}
```

creating an concrete class does not work, because the constructor is not visible and calling the constructor via reflection API also doesn't work because the class is abstract.

I need to create an instance of android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback

Comment: Instance of an abstract class??? There's no such thing..

Comment: **"I need to create an instance of android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback"** : Why? All you have to do is create a class which extends `PrintDocumentAdapter` and make sure you override `onLayout(...)` to make use of the `LayoutResultCallback`.

Comment: I know that it is not possible to create a direct instance of this class because it is abstact, but a inherit class is also not possible because the constructor is hidden, this is the problem.

Comment: I want to use an existing `PrintDocumentAdapter` from `WebView.createPrintDocumentAdapter(String documentName)` to convert a web page into an PDF, I know that i could use the PrintManager to save PDF, but this must work without user interaction, so i want so I want to call onStart, onLayout, onWrite of the PrintDocumentAdapter by myself.

Comment: @Andreas Were you able to successfully create a PDF from a WebView using this method? I'm trying to do the same thing...

Comment: @user2771609 As i wrote in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/29917077/2190817 i was able to create a PDF from a WebView. Unfortunately, i had not enough free time to create a library. Also because my solution currently compiles only on targetApi 19. It works on Android 5.x but not with targetAPI > 19 because is was not able to get the framework.jar. Maybe your sulotion to create LayoutResultCallback instance will solve the problem. I will try it tomorrow :)

Comment: I got it working using the dexmaker library solution below. There are some quirks though. When the LayoutResultCallback is executed, the PrintDocumentInfo object is not quite valid -- the page count shows -1, so I cannot get the number of pages etc. And when I call onWrite, it ignores my pageRange arguments, and always writes all the pages. Those are not big problems for me, but it is just a little weird...

Comment: this i because this is not yet implemented in the PrintDocumentAdapter of the Webview. The onLayout method does nothing and therefore returns a pageCount of -1. The layout is done in the onWrite Method which ignores the pageRange argument.

Comment: Ah, thank you. That is nice to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into precisely the same problem (for precisely the same class even) and I have a better solution than replacing the android.jar with framework.jar as suggested in the other answer.

The solution uses the [dexmaker library](https://github.com/crittercism/dexmaker). (You will need dexmaker.1.4.jar and dexmaker-dx.1.4.jar). This is a library that generates bytecode at runtime for the Dalvik VM (the VM used in android).

This library has a class called `ProxyBuilder` that generates a *proxy* for an abstract class. The proxy is an object that **extends the abstract class** and implements the methods by dispatching them to an instance of `java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler` that you specify.

`ProxyBuilder` is almost identical to `java.lang.refect.Proxy`, except that `java.lang.refect.Proxy` only works for interfaces, while dexmaker's `ProxyBuilder` works for abstract classes, which is what we need for our problem.

The code is all of:

```
public static PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback getLayoutResultCallback(InvocationHandler invocationHandler,
                                                                                File dexCacheDir) throws  IOException{
    return ProxyBuilder.forClass(PrintDocumentAdapter.LayoutResultCallback.class)
            .dexCache(dexCacheDir)
            .handler(invocationHandler)
            .build();
}
```

The callback logic is implemented in the `invocationHandler` that you provide.
The `cacheDir` is some directory where dexmaker can store some files.

Comment: Thanks for that solution, i will try it in a few days :)

Comment: does this work with Android 5.x? because Dalvik was replaced by ART in Android 5.0

Comment: Yes. I tested it on Android 6. It seems like the ART uses the same bytecode as Dalvik: "[ART and Dalvik are compatible runtimes running Dex bytecode](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/)". Since dexmaker generate Dex bytecode, dexmaker works for ART as well.

Comment: Where can i find this dexmaker-dx-1.4.jar? On the github site of the projekt there is only a download for the dexmaker-1.4.jar. Is the second jar file really necessary?

Comment: You can find it here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crittercism.dexmaker. I did need both. I don't understand why it is packaged like this and why there is not information about it in the Github Readme, but It worked for me...

Comment: I marked your answer as the accepted one. The other answer is also working perfect but requires manipulation the android.jar everytime you update your targetApi

Comment: @user2771609 I was looking for exactly the same class, `LayoutResultCallback`. Didn't try it yet, but seems like a solution. Are you trying to use `PrintDocumentAdapter`'s `onLayout` method as well ?

Comment: Yes, this was for `PrintDocumentAdapter`'s `onLayout`. I used it on a `WebView` to convert a webpage to pdf. It worked fine. If you are using this for a `WebView` like I did, you should know that the `PrintDocumentInfo` you get in `onLayoutFinished` is not useful. `onLayout` actually does nothing it seems in `WebView`. The `onWrite` is where the layout actually happens.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial seems to address how to do what you are asking: https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/. I have never done this myself so I cannot vouch for it.

**Be warned:** there is a reason that methods in the API are hidden. The most important for developers is that there is no guarantee that the method will stick around for any length of time as the method in question is not part of any public API.

Comment: I think in this case it will be safe to use the class, because the class itself and the methods are not hidden or in the internal API, only the constructor ist hidden.

Comment: In this case, you are probably correct. However, the signature of the constructor (parameter types, etc) could still change without warning (it may even be different on different versions of Android). I am not trying to stop you from doing what you are trying to do but just make sure you understand sources of possible runtime errors that you may encounter on other versions of Android.

Comment: link is no longer accessible without login.